# Windows task manager CPU "uptime computer" time for app/project?

Tags: java

I want to make a class with different methods to track time for an app/project.

I have tried to look for things linked to time an system(cpu)(up)time.
But can't seem to find anything that's good to finish with.

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter currentDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
public static final DateTimeFormatter currentTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss");
public static Date D;
public static Time T;
public static LocalDateTime localDateTime; 
private static String R;

public static String getTime(){
    D = new Date();
    T = new Time(D.getTime());
    R = T.toString();
    return R;
}
public static String getDate(){
    localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    R = localDateTime.format(currentDateFormat).toString();
    return R;
}
public static String getTimeAndDate(){
    D = new Date();
    R = D.toString();
    return R;
}
```

This works like I want it to work.

The output of the method is a string with the current "CPU uptime" time in the format "hh:mm:ss".

```
public static String getSystemTime(){
    /*
             !!!code to be added!!!
            */
    return R;
}
```

What I want is the time displayed in the "Windows task manager" labelled as "uptime/active time" for the CPU/processor:
[image: location of windows task manager uptime/active time of the CPU]

Comment: According to [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/954149/39645) that time might be the difference between the current time and the last system boot time, i.e. it includes time that the machine was asleep. Which doesn't seem that useful to me.

Comment: Maybe [`ProcessHandle.Info`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html) (obtained via `ProcessHandle.current().info()`)?